# Why do I get this error in this omp_declare_reduction?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, reduce

I have this file:

**A.h**

```
struct B;

struct A
{
    A(... B &b) :
        b(b) {}

    B &b;
};
```

And **B.h**:

```
#include "A.h"
struct B{
...
std::vector<A> as;
}
```

And I have this `omp_declare_reduction`:

```
#pragma omp declare reduction(merge : B : omp_out.as.insert(omp_out.as.end(), omp_in.as.begin(), omp_in.as.end()))
```

However, I get this error (where `A=FindAffineShapeArgs` and `B=Wrapper`):

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h(564): error: function "FindAffineShapeArgs::operator=(const FindAffineShapeArgs &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
        *--__result = std::move(*--__last);
                    ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1=FindAffineShapeArgs *, _BI2=FindAffineShapeArgs *]" at line 606
            instantiation of "_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a<_IsMove,_BI1,_BI2>(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _IsMove=true, _BI1=FindAffineShapeArgs *, _BI2=FindAffineShapeArgs *]" at line 615
            instantiation of "_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a2<_IsMove,_BI1,_BI2>(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _IsMove=true, _BI1=FindAffineShapeArgs *, _BI2=FindAffineShapeArgs *]" at line 686
            instantiation of "_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1=FindAffineShapeArgs *, _BI2=FindAffineShapeArgs *]" at line 636 of "/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc"
            instantiation of "void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _Tp=FindAffineShapeArgs, _Alloc=std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>, _ForwardIterator=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>]" at line 1377 of "/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h"
            instantiation of "void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_dispatch(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _Tp=FindAffineShapeArgs, _Alloc=std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>, _InputIterator=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>]" at line 1100 of "/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h"
            instantiation of "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _Tp=FindAffineShapeArgs, _Alloc=std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>, _InputIterator=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>, <unnamed>=void]" at line 345 of
                      "/home/luca/Dropbox/HKUST/CloudCache/cloudcache/CloudCache/Descriptors/hesaff/pyramid.cpp"

    /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h(340): error: function "FindAffineShapeArgs::operator=(const FindAffineShapeArgs &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
              *__result = *__first;
                        ^
              detected during:
                instantiation of "_OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II=FindAffineShapeArgs *, _OI=FindAffineShapeArgs *]" at line 402
                instantiation of "_OI std::__copy_move_a<_IsMove,_II,_OI>(_II, _II, _OI) [with _IsMove=false, _II=FindAffineShapeArgs *, _OI=FindAffineShapeArgs *]" at line 440
                instantiation of "_OI std::__copy_move_a2<_IsMove,_II,_OI>(_II, _II, _OI) [with _IsMove=false, _II=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>, _OI=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>]" at line 472
                instantiation of "_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>, _OI=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>]" at line 637 of "/usr/include/c++/5/bits/vector.tcc"
                instantiation of "void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _Tp=FindAffineShapeArgs, _Alloc=std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>, _ForwardIterator=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>]" at line 1377 of "/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h"
                instantiation of "void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_dispatch(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _Tp=FindAffineShapeArgs, _Alloc=std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>, _InputIterator=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>]" at line 1100 of "/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h"
                instantiation of "std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _Tp=FindAffineShapeArgs, _Alloc=std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>, _InputIterator=__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<FindAffineShapeArgs *, std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs, std::allocator<FindAffineShapeArgs>>>, <unnamed>=void]" at line 345 of
                          "/home/luca/Dropbox/HKUST/CloudCache/cloudcache/CloudCache/Descriptors/hesaff/pyramid.cpp"

    compilation aborted for /home/luca/Dropbox/HKUST/CloudCache/cloudcache/CloudCache/Descriptors/hesaff/pyramid.cpp (code 2)
```

Why this happens? This could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550191/circular-dependency-and-stdvectorinsert) but for a different case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with omp, or the apparent circular reference (there's nothing wrong with your circular reference *per se*, here). You'll get a similar compilation error with:

```
#include <vector>

struct B {};

struct A
{
    A(B &b) :
        b(b) {}

    B &b;
};


B b;
A a{b}, aa{b};

void foo()
{
        a=aa;
}
```

gcc error's message, in thid case, will point you to the clue:

```
t.C:19:4: error: use of deleted function ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)’
```

Classes containing references do not have a default assignment operator. This is because references cannot be changed, or "assigned to", in the traditional sense.

You are creating a `std::vector`, which needs to copy/move around its values, as needed. But the vector's class contains a reference member, which nukes the class's assignment operator from high orbit.

In order to make this happen, you need to define your own assignment operator and/or copy constructor for the `A` class, and have them do what you need them to do.

Comment: So what I need to do is creating a copy constructor  `A(... const B &b) :` , right? That's a pain, since I need to modify `b` inside `A`...

Comment: @justHelloWorld You could store something assignable, like a pointer.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: @SamVarshavchik could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43844396/how-should-i-interpreter-these-vtune-results) question?